# How do I use code to identify which method or function a certain line of code is run in?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I am using Xcode to create an iOS app using Swift, and I would like to create a global function that displays an alert controller. I pass the view controller that will present the alert controller as an argument to the function. When I call the function, I send the self variable as an argument for the presenting view controller, since the function is called from the currently showing view controller.

I would like the alert controller to be able to display where the function was called for. The view controller object that was passed as an argument to the function has a way of expressing its identity as a string value. I can set the alert message to show that string value.

Is there a way for me to use code to identify which method in the view controller object my global function was called from? Another way of thinking about it is: Is there a way for a line of code to be able to determine which scope it is in?

Here is what I've discovered when I tried what I want to do in code:

```
print("self: \(self)")
```

Result in debug window:

```
self: <TempSingleViewApp.ViewController: 0x10380b7d0>
```

Comment: Are you looking for `#function`? https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a neat way to do this:

Have your global function have a string parameter with a default value, and assign the default value as `"\(#function)"`:

```
func globalFunction(param: String, calledFromFunction: String = "\(#function)") {
    print("Called from \(calledFromFunction)")
    // Your function body
}
```

Then never override the default value, and the compiler will fill in the calling function's name in calls to it.

Note that because this is a parameter, it does mean that for a function used for record-keeping, somebody could "spoof" the calling function by passing in an explicit parameter.

Comment: I tried that. For some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not very informative. What results do you get?

Comment: I happen to be looking at the documentation, and figured out that there was a mistake in your code. Instead of putting the literal inside of quotation marks, it should just be as itself like so: func globalFunction(_ param: String = String = #function) { print(param) }. That will print the exact name of the function where globalFunction is called as long as you don’t pass an argument to the function and allow the function to use the default argument.

Comment: That works with any of the literals.